# Flash AS3 :How to save levels of  AIR mobile game on local machine? 

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I just need to know how to save my mobile AIR game levels on local machine. Like all the details should be get save eg. how much level i finished or opened once and played, those levels should be in unlocked state. If the level which was never open before will be in locked state. This is my concept and this is the concept used in all mobile games nowadays. kindly please go through any mobile game level type and please let me know the coding for my concept its very urgent. And Thanks in advance. Any help will be kindly appreciatable.

The code which i used is below:
Flash AS3

```
var file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("test.txt"); 
var str = "Locked Levels : Level 1,Level 2,Level 3,Level 4"; 
file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileSaved); 
file.save(str); 
function fileSaved(event) 
{ 
    trace("Done."); 
}
```

In the above code the text document is getting write to my local machine. But i don't know how to check the levels which are locked are unlocked using this . i kept my level buttons on stage itself by using frames for lock and unlock position.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry Mr.weltraumpirat, though i was new to stack i made that mistake.I assured the mistake i did will be never happen hereafter and also i rectified my mistake and edited my question. So please help me to get the right solution and also help me to get reputations to improve my knowledge over on stack. Already i had only less amount of reputation though u marked as poor question i lost my 4 reputations out Mr weltraumpirat. so please help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its k weltraumpirat . if possible please help me to get any reputation please .

Comment: Why someone just down-voted this question ?

Comment: I don't know Mr Adrian Pirvulescu someone down voted my question . I think they couldn't understand the concept i think. And finally i got solution for my problem the solution is below. I used this concept and it works fine. Solution :::SharedObject.getLocal("xxxxx")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use the built in SQLite feature of Adobe AIR. 
   For this you can create a local database that you can query later.

OR

2. Save data to applicationstoragefolder in your own format, so you can read it later and interpret it.

Personally, I would go for encrypted SQLite so you can get out of "hacking" scores by the "bad" guys :)

Comment: Just as a comment... I would always integrate my app/game with GameCenter :) This way the user: already has an account, can have achievements, in iOS6 he can share on facebook or invite friends..

Comment: I couldn't get you Mr. Adrian pirvulescu. wt u are trying to say?

Comment: Since you develop a game, if you plan to post it to Apple AppStore you can integrate it with Apple GameCenter. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/gamecenter-ane-ios.html

Comment: k pirvulescu.I will try it and let u know if i have any doubt.

Comment: And what about Android? Is there something similar to the GameCenter?

Comment: Unfortunately by now there is no Android Game-Center. But there are rumors about it http://www.electronista.com/articles/12/05/10/google.working.on.native.game.center.app/

Answer (score 2):

Here you will find some infos about working with SQL in AIR: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5497-7fb4.html

And here you will find a tutorial:
http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.de/2011/05/creating-air-application-with-sqlite.html